# What directory does netplan write networkd config to?

Tags: netplan, systemd-networkd

Where does netplan output its configuration to? `/etc/systemd/network` is empty, even though netplan uses networkd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netplan outputs to `/run/systemd/network/`. This config is recreated each time during boot.